# Converting Parquet to Avro

Tags: avro, parquet

I see plenty of examples on how to convert Avro files to Parquet, with Parquet retaining the Avro schema in its metadata.

I'm confused however on if there's some simple way of doing the opposite - converting Parquet to Avro. Any examples of that?

Answer (score 0):

I think with Impala with some query like that should work :

```
CREATE TABLE parquet_table(....)  STORED AS PARQUET;
CREATE TABLE avro_table(....)  STORED AS AVRO;


INSERT INTO avro_table SELECT  * FROM parquet_table;
```

Parquet data stored in parquet_table will be converted into avro format into avro_table.